# How to get value from a certain row in a Gridview that was filled by SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a way to delete multiple accounts with Gridview by adding a checkbox per row. I did this by adding an `TemplateField` in the Gridview. Using Gridview's smart tab, I then placed a Checkbox with an ID `DeleteSelector`

My ASP.NET markup is like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tbl_departments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="department_ID" HeaderText="department_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="department_Name" HeaderText="department_Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="DeleteSelector" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

At `Page_Load` it is filled with data:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM department_Information;";
    tbl_departments.DataSource = SQL_Connect.GridFill(query);
    tbl_departments.DataBind();
}
```

My code is like this:

```
protected void btn_deleteSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> Fetch_ID = new List<string>();
    string connection_String = "Data Source = Lap; Initial Catalog = Database; User ID = ***; Password = ***";

    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(connection_String);

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox CheckBoxControl = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("DeleteSelector");

        if (CheckBoxControl != null && CheckBoxControl.Checked)
        {
            var dept_ID = (GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            Fetch_ID.Add((dept_ID).ToString());
        }
    }

    string[] Process_ID = Fetch_ID.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < Process_ID.Length; i++)
    {
        Connection.Open();
        string query = "DELETE FROM department_Information WHERE department_ID ='" + Process_ID[i] + "';";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Connection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I can't proceed to check if my DELETE approach is correct, because before C# could reach that point, it is throwing an exception at this line...

```
var dept_ID = (GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
```

The exception was...

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range.
>   Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index'

I reckon it has something to do with the Datakeys so I proceed to check it out using MessageBox; and sure enough, it has a value of 0

```
string insert = GridView1.DataKeys.Count.ToString();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(insert);
```

By this point, I have no idea on how to correct this. Is there a way to fill the Datakeys? In-general, is there a way (or an alternative way) to get a value from a certain row in a Gridview when it's Checkbox was checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through your code I've noticed in your markup you have not added any `DataKeyNames` so please add a `DataKeyNames` attribute in your `GridView`. Hence, your `GridView` Markup should like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="tbl_departments" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="department_ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="department_ID" HeaderText="department_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="department_Name" HeaderText="department_Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="DeleteSelector" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Notice I have added the attribute `DataKeyNames="department_ID"` this will let GridView know that these are the keys that you will be getting in the code behind.

**UPDATE**

Answering your second question: *In-general, is there a way (or an alternative way) to get a value from a certain row in a Gridview when it's Checkbox was checked*

Yes, the same way you are reading the checkboxes but the way to read the ID without setting DataKeyNames attribute you will have to have a column inside your GridView with the ID that you want to fetch.
I notice, you have a `BoundField` for `department_ID` in your GridView columns so you can fetch it from there as well like below:

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

This will give you the text in the Cell at 0 index that is inside the row at 0 index.